# Torrent scraper

Tags: php, torrent

i'm using scrape torrents and show the seeds of them, I use the script that I found on the internet and it uses socket to connect the tracker and get the data, it run on my localhost with xampp server but when it does not server works, it does not catch the seeds of the stream and the script generates an error message

Script msg:

> Error: Could not open HTTP connection. Connection error: yes The
> script:

Code 1 (udptracker.php):

```
<?php
    /*  Torrent UDP Scraper
        v1.2
        
        2010 by Johannes Zinnau
        johannes@johnimedia.de
        
        Licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
        http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
        
        It would be very nice if you send me your changes on this class, so that i can include them if they are improve it.
        Thanks!
        
        Usage:
        try{
            $timeout = 2;
            
            $scraper = new udptscraper($timeout);
            $ret = $scraper->scrape('udp://tracker.tld:port',array('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'));
            
            print_r($ret);
        }catch(ScraperException $e){
            echo('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n");
            echo('Connection error: ' . ($e->isConnectionError() ? 'yes' : 'no') . "<br />\n");
        }
    */

include "tscraper.php";

    class udptscraper extends tscraper{


        /*  $url: Tracker url like: udp://tracker.tld:port or udp://tracker.tld:port/announce
            $infohash: Infohash string or array (max 74 items). 40 char long infohash. 
            */
        public function scrape($url,$infohash){
            if(!is_array($infohash)){ $infohash = array($infohash); }
            foreach($infohash as $hash){
                if(!preg_match('#^[a-f0-9]{40}$#i',$hash)){ throw new ScraperException('Invalid infohash: ' . $hash . '.'); }
            }
            if(count($infohash) > 74){ throw new ScraperException('Too many infohashes provided.'); }
            if(!preg_match('%udp://([^:/]*)(?::([0-9]*))?(?:/)?%si', $url, $m)){ throw new ScraperException('Invalid tracker url.'); }
            $tracker = 'udp://' . $m[1];
            $port = isset($m[2]) ? $m[2] : 80;


            $transaction_id = mt_rand(0,65535);
            $fp = fsockopen($tracker, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if(!$fp){ throw new ScraperException('Could not open UDP connection: ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errstr,0,true); }
            stream_set_timeout($fp, $this->timeout);


            $current_connid = "\x00\x00\x04\x17\x27\x10\x19\x80";


            //Connection request
            $packet = $current_connid . pack("N", 0) . pack("N", $transaction_id);
            fwrite($fp,$packet);


            //Connection response
            $ret = fread($fp, 16);
            if(strlen($ret) < 1){ throw new ScraperException('No connection response.',0,true); }
            if(strlen($ret) < 16){ throw new ScraperException('Too short connection response.'); }
            $retd = unpack("Naction/Ntransid",$ret);
            if($retd['action'] != 0 || $retd['transid'] != $transaction_id){
                throw new ScraperException('Invalid connection response.');
            }
            $current_connid = substr($ret,8,8);


            //Scrape request
            $hashes = '';
            foreach($infohash as $hash){ $hashes .= pack('H*', $hash); }
            $packet = $current_connid . pack("N", 2) . pack("N", $transaction_id) . $hashes;
            fwrite($fp,$packet);


            //Scrape response
            $readlength = 8 + (12 * count($infohash));
            $ret = fread($fp, $readlength);
            if(strlen($ret) < 1){ throw new ScraperException('No scrape response.',0,true); }
            if(strlen($ret) < 8){ throw new ScraperException('Too short scrape response.'); }
            $retd = unpack("Naction/Ntransid",$ret);
            // Todo check for error string if response = 3
            if($retd['action'] != 2 || $retd['transid'] != $transaction_id){
                throw new ScraperException('Invalid scrape response.');
            }
            if(strlen($ret) < $readlength){ throw new ScraperException('Too short scrape response.'); }
            $torrents = array();
            $index = 8;
            foreach($infohash as $hash){
                $retd = unpack("Nseeders/Ncompleted/Nleechers",substr($ret,$index,12));
                $retd['infohash'] = $hash;
                $torrents[$hash] = $retd;
                $index = $index + 12;
            }


            return($torrents);
        }
    }
?>
```

Code 2:

```
<?php
include "httptscraper.php";

$scrap1 = "$row[torrent]";
preg_match('#magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:(?<hash>.*?)&dn=(?<filename>.*?)&tr=(?<trackers>.*?)$#', $scrap1, $magnet_link);
$magnet_link['trackers'] = explode('&', urldecode(str_replace('tr=','', $magnet_link['trackers'])));
$resultados2 = $magnet_link['trackers'][0];
$resultados1 = $magnet_link['hash'];

try{
            $timeout = 2;
            
            $scraper = new udptscraper($timeout);
            $ret = $scraper->scrape($resultados2,array($resultados1));
            
            $array = $ret[$resultados1];
            $array2 = $array['seeders'];
            print_r($array2);
        }catch(ScraperException $e){
            echo "Sem Info";
            //echo('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n");
            //echo('Connection error: ' . ($e->isConnectionError() ? 'yes' : 'no') . "<br />\n");
        }
?>
```

Code 3 (tscraper.php):

```
<?php
/*  Torrent Scraper Base Class
    v1.0
    
    2010 by Johannes Zinnau
    johannes@johnimedia.de
    
    Licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License
    http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
    
    It would be very nice if you send me your changes on this class, so that i can include them if they are improve it.
    Thanks!
    
    Usage:
    See udptscraper.php or httptscraper.php
*/


class ScraperException extends Exception {
    private $connectionerror;


    public function __construct($message,$code=0,$connectionerror=false){
        $this->connectionerror = $connectionerror;
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }


    public function isConnectionError(){
        return($this->connectionerror);
    }
}


abstract class tscraper {
    protected $timeout;


    public function __construct($timeout=2){
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: which tracker you are queering to ? is it up?

Answer (score 0):

You server seems to be blocking the requests. In this case you will need to find a torrent friendly server. Take a look here: http://filesharefreak.com/2009/10/09/the-best-hosting-providers-for-private-trackers. You can also try some servers in countries like, i dont know, Sweden?

Comment: The url in the answer above is bad.